Error CORS Prime Ng (p-fileUpload)
Tengo un problema con PrimeNG al intentar subir archivos. Recibo el siguiente error: "Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La política de mismo origen (Same Origin Policy) no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en 1  https://www.primefaces.org/cdn/api/upload.php". Estoy utilizando PrimeNG 16 y Angular 16. He intentado buscar solución pero no la he encontrado. ¿Alguien ha tenido un problema similar y sabe cómo solucionarlo?


